# Disable pagination on frontpage

Tags: pagination, homepage, paginate-links

My home page is being build on **index.php**. I have a wordpress loop somewhere there, because I want to show the two latest posts. So my problem is that my homepage is being paginated. I don't want that.

I want my homepage to act as a homepage. Lets say my homepage is **example.com**, and shows the latest 2 posts **example.com**/*page/2/* it show the previous two. I've added that code in the top of the index.php but is just a redirection. I want the pagination just disabled for that specific loop. How can I achieve that?

Thank you

`<?php if ($paged > 1) { header('Location: /blog'); exit; } ?>`

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the WordPress [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), by either having a [`home.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) - home page - or a [`front-page.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) - front page - to display the site home/front. Read the WordPress codex article [Creating a Static Front Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) for an insight on how to do it and some explanation about the differences. Do not use any pagination code - see the according [section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Pagination) from the before mentioned article.

Comment: So i'm making a front-page.php template, create a page, and assign that page as Front Page in settings->reading right?

Comment: Did you read what I linked? @hambos22